# Swagger UI Not Working With Webflux (returning 404)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, swagger-ui

I cannot get Swagger UI working with Webflux.

According to countless [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62790166/2468620) here, you should be able to just add `springfox-boot-starter` and it should work.

I have created a [minimum reproducible example](https://github.com/Jardo-51/webflux-swagger-ui) which you can download and run. It is a plain project from Spring Initializr with Webflux and a single testing endpoint on path `/hello`. Trying to open the swagger UI always returns 404. I have tried the official path `/swagger-ui/` as well as all other possible options such as `/swagger-ui.html`, `/swagger-ui/index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

For spring-boot 3 support, make sure you use springdoc-openapi v2. This does not requires any kind of configuration as such.
Swagger can be accessed using
http:localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html

Link:
[SpringDocs](https://springdoc.org/v2/)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```